# Set width of list items to fill unordered list

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have a horizontal unordered list with a set width. Inside, I have a dynamic number of list items. It could be 2 items, or 6 - it depends on several factors.

I'd like to be able to set the width of each list item so that they fill the entire width of the ul, no matter how many items are inside. So if there was 1 list item, it's width would be 100%; 2, and they would both be 50%, and so on.

Here's my HTML and CSS:

```
ul
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #000000;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li
{
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #4265CE;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Here it is in jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vDVvm/3/

Is there a way to do this with CSS, or will I have to use jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No way with pure CSS, I'm afraid.

Edit: Most proper jQuery solution i can think of: http://jsfiddle.net/vDVvm/8/

```
(function( $ ){
  $.fn.autowidth = function() {
    return this.each(function() {        
        $('li', this).css({'width' : (100 / $('li', this).length) + '%'})
    });
  };
})( jQuery );

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fill-me').autowidth();    
});
```

Keep in mind though, that whenever (100 % number_of_lis !== 0), you're gonna be running into some nasty problems with rounding errors.

Comment: meh... yours is better... my version of what you did would be this: `$("ul li").css({width:(100/$("ul li").length)+"%"});`

Answer (score 4):

A solution without JavaScript.

```
ul
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #000000;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: table;
}

li
{
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #4265CE;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vDVvm/5/

It may be not cross browser enough, however.

Comment: Meh. Unfortunately, display:table-cell often leads to unexpected results. Not cross-browser indeed.

Comment: Also, see (very hypothetical, admittedly) scenario here: http://jsfiddle.net/vDVvm/9/ - the &lt;ul&gt; stops caring about its width at some point, to accomodate all &lt;li&gt;s including their text.

Comment: If there is too many items, there is no way to put them in a fixed box without scrollbars. JavaScript, Java, Flash or anything else will not help.

Answer (score 3):

This is also possible just with css, but will only work in modern browsers.

```
ul {
    /* ... */
    display: table;
}

li {
    /* ... */
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, you can do something like this :

```
var li = $('#mylist li').size();
var liWidth = 100 / li;

$('#mylist li').width(liWidth + '%');
```

assuming your HTML looks like:

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that uses each and every li on the page for calculating the width …

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vDVvm/7/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improvement on vzwick's function:

```
(function( $ ){
  $.fn.autowidth = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var w = $(this).width();
        var liw = w / $(this).children('li').length;
        $(this).children('li').each(function(){
            var s = $(this).outerWidth(true)-$(this).width();
            $(this).width(liw-s);
        });
    });
  };
})( jQuery );
```